# OSError: Failed to load library from libmediainfo.so.0

Tags: google-colaboratory

OSError: Failed to load library from libmediainfo.so.0 - libmediainfo.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I install libmediainfo.so.0 in colab? Doesn't it work in colab?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can solve it by running the command "sudo apt install mediainfo" in the terminal. (was not my idea i found it  on https://github.com/sbraz/pymediainfo/issues/109 and it worked)